# How does the stack work?

Tags: memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I have a couple questions about the stack. One thing I don't understand about the stack is the "pop" and "push" idea. Say I have integers a and b, with a above b on the stack. To access b, as I understand it, a would have to be popped off the stack to access b. So where is "a" stored when it is popped off the stack.

Also if stack memory is more efficient to access than heap memory, why isn't heap memory structured like the stack? Thanks.

Comment: The heap is not structured like the stack because you can't structure memory like a stack, and still use it for what the heap is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So where is "a" stored when it is popped off the stack.

It depends. It goes where the program that's reading the stack decides. It may store the value, ignore it, print it, anything.

> Also if stack memory is more efficient to access than heap memory, why
>   isn't heap memory structured like the stack?

A stack isn't more efficient to access than a heap is, it depends on the usage. The program's flow gets deeper and shallower just like a stack does. Local variables, arguments and return addresses are, in mainstream languages, stored in a stack structure because this kind of structure implements more easily the semantics of what we call a function's stack frame. A function can very efficiently access its own stack frame, but not necessarily its caller functions' stack frames, that is, the whole stack.

On the other hand, the heap would be inefficient if it were implemented that way, because it's expected for the heap to be able to access and possibly delete items anywhere, not just from its top/bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but you can sort of think of this like the [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) puzzle. To access a lower disc, you "pop" discs above it and place them elsewhere - in this case, on other stacks, but in the case of programming it could be just a simple variable or pointer or anything. When you've got the item you need, then the other ones can be put back on the stack or moved elsewhere entirely.

Comment: Ok thanks. But I still don't understand where the variables that have been "popped" are placed.

Comment: @Iowa15 I still do not understand.. I have the same question in my head as you do.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is stored wherever you decide to store it. :-) You need to provide a variable in which to store the value at the top of the stack (`a`) when you remove it, then remove the next item (`b`) and store it in a different variable to use it, and then push the first value (`a`) back on the stack.

Picture an actual pile of dirty plates sitting on your counter to your left. You pick one up to wash it (pop it from the "dirty" stack), wash it, dry it, and put it on the top of the clean stack (push it) on your right.

If you want to reach the second plate from the top in either stack, you have to move the top one to get to it. So you pick it up (pop it), put it somewhere temporarily, pick up the next plate (pop it) and put it somewhere, and then put the first one you removed back on the pile (push it back on the stack).

If you can't picture it with plates, use an actual deck of playing cards (or baseball cards, or a stack of paper - anything you can neatly pile ("stack")) and put it on your desk at your left hand. Then perform the steps in my last paragraph, replacing the word "plate" with "card" and physically performing the steps.

So to access `b`, you declare a variable to store `a` in, pop `a` and save it in that variable, pop `b` into it's own variable, and then push `a` back onto the stack.

Comment: So where is that temporary place where you store the plate?

Comment: Read what I wrote in my last paragraph again, and think about it. Picture it with the plates, with your left hand picking up the top plate (a temporary storage location, which in programming is a variable), grab the next one in your right (a different variable), and then put the one from your left hand back on the pile.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take your case scenario .

You have a stack with *n* elements on it, the last one is **a**, **b** is underneath.

*pop* operation returns the popped value, so if you want to access the second from the top being **b**, you could do:

```
var temp = stack.pop()
var b = stack.pop()
stack.push(temp)
```

However, stack would rarely be used this way. It is a LIFO queue and works best when accessed like a LIFO queue.

It seems you would rather need a collection with a random index based access. 
That collection would probably be stored on the heap. Hope it clarified stack pop/push a little.